# How to start an instance with a custom identifier

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, instance

So I'm going to be starting multiple instances of one of my C# scripts, but I will later need to be able to reference individual instances to terminate or modify properties within. For an example:

```
   _numInputs = 5;

        for(int i = 0; i < _numInputs; i++)
        {
            Input input = new Input();
        }
```

How would I go about throwing the value of "i" onto the end of the instance label?

Input input[i] = new Input(); ??? lol I know that doesn't work but just to clarify my goal. Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: Are they being serialized or something? Why can't you just use a closure?

Comment: Because I'd never heard of a closure before! XD but thank you for the new info! I'll certainly research that! (Oh the ignorance gained from self-teaching.)

Comment: Closures are at the heart of modern C# techniques. They are very fun to work with, enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is an array of `Instance`:

```
Input[] inputs = new Input[_numInputs];
for(int i = 0; i < _numInputs; i++)
{
    inputs[i] = new Input();
}
```

Comment: Absolutely glorious! XD ty so much! I knew I'd seen many people do this before but couldn't remember how! I'll accept your answer in 10min when Stack lets me. lol

Comment: the _numInputs did need to be a static member too btw. however, worked fine, thanks!